# Gcc's -fleading-underscore option

Tags: c, gcc

Compiling a sample C program test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    puts("TEST");
    return 0;
}
```

with gcc 10.2.1 (on Debian GNU/Linux running on WSL 2) with default options (`gcc test.c`) works fine, but adding `-fleading-underscore` option produces an error:

```
gcc -fleading-underscore test.c
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc8SXM3o.o: in function `_main':
test.c:(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `_puts'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Interestingly, gcc -Q -V test.c shows `-fleading-underscore` among enabled options.

```
$ gcc -Q -v test.c
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:amdgcn-amdhsa:hsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 10.2.1-6' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-10/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,m2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-10 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-10-Km9U7s/gcc-10-10.2.1/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,amdgcn-amdhsa=/build/gcc-10-Km9U7s/gcc-10-10.2.1/debian/tmp-gcn/usr,hsa --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto-lean --enable-link-mutex
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 10.2.1 20210110 (Debian 10.2.1-6)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-Q' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/cc1 -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu test.c -dumpbase test.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase test -version -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -o /tmp/ccFkJ2ej.s
GNU C17 (Debian 10.2.1-6) version 10.2.1 20210110 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
        compiled by GNU C version 10.2.1 20210110, GMP version 6.2.1, MPFR version 4.1.0, MPC version 1.2.0, isl version isl-0.23-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C17 (Debian 10.2.1-6) version 10.2.1 20210110 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
        compiled by GNU C version 10.2.1 20210110, GMP version 6.2.1, MPFR version 4.1.0, MPC version 1.2.0, isl version isl-0.23-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
options passed:  -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu test.c -mtune=generic
 -march=x86-64 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables
options enabled:  -fPIC -fPIE -faggressive-loop-optimizations
 -fallocation-dce -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fauto-inc-dec
 -fdelete-null-pointer-checks -fdwarf2-cfi-asm -fearly-inlining
 -feliminate-unused-debug-symbols -feliminate-unused-debug-types
 -ffp-int-builtin-inexact -ffunction-cse -fgcse-lm -fgnu-unique -fident
 -finline-atomics -fipa-stack-alignment -fira-hoist-pressure
 -fira-share-save-slots -fira-share-spill-slots -fivopts
 -fkeep-static-consts -fleading-underscore -flifetime-dse -fmath-errno
 -fmerge-debug-strings -fpeephole -fplt -fprefetch-loop-arrays
 -freg-struct-return -fsched-critical-path-heuristic
 -fsched-dep-count-heuristic -fsched-group-heuristic -fsched-interblock
 -fsched-last-insn-heuristic -fsched-rank-heuristic -fsched-spec
 -fsched-spec-insn-heuristic -fsched-stalled-insns-dep -fschedule-fusion
 -fsemantic-interposition -fshow-column -fshrink-wrap-separate
 -fsigned-zeros -fsplit-ivs-in-unroller -fssa-backprop -fstdarg-opt
 -fstrict-volatile-bitfields -fsync-libcalls -ftrapping-math -ftree-cselim
 -ftree-forwprop -ftree-loop-if-convert -ftree-loop-im -ftree-loop-ivcanon
 -ftree-loop-optimize -ftree-parallelize-loops= -ftree-phiprop
 -ftree-reassoc -ftree-scev-cprop -funit-at-a-time -funwind-tables
 -fvar-tracking -fvar-tracking-assignments -fzero-initialized-in-bss
 -m128bit-long-double -m64 -m80387 -malign-stringops
 -mavx256-split-unaligned-load -mavx256-split-unaligned-store
 -mfancy-math-387 -mfp-ret-in-387 -mfxsr -mglibc -mieee-fp -mlong-double-80
 -mmmx -mno-sse4 -mpush-args -mred-zone -msse -msse2 -mstv
 -mtls-direct-seg-refs -mvzeroupper
Compiler executable checksum: 1f803793fa2e3418c492b25e7d3eac2f
 main
Analyzing compilation unit
Performing interprocedural optimizations
 <*free_lang_data> {heap 876k} <visibility> {heap 876k} <build_ssa_passes> {heap 876k} <opt_local_passes> {heap 1068k} <remove_symbols> {heap 1068k} <targetclone> {heap 1068k} <free-fnsummary> {heap 1068k}Streaming LTO
 <whole-program> {heap 1068k} <hsa> {heap 1068k} <fnsummary> {heap 1068k} <inline> {heap 1068k} <free-fnsummary> {heap 1068k} <single-use> {heap 1068k} <comdats> {heap 1068k}Assembling functions:
 <materialize-all-clones> {heap 1068k} <simdclone> {heap 1068k} main
Time variable                                   usr           sys          wall               GGC
 phase setup                        :   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)    1240 kB ( 70%)
 phase parsing                      :   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 ( 50%)   0.01 (100%)     460 kB ( 26%)
 phase opt and generate             :   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 ( 50%)   0.00 (  0%)      56 kB (  3%)
 preprocessing                      :   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 ( 50%)   0.00 (  0%)     133 kB (  8%)
 integrated RA                      :   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 ( 50%)   0.00 (  0%)      24 kB (  1%)
 symout                             :   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (100%)       0 kB (  0%)
 TOTAL                              :   0.00          0.02          0.01           1768 kB
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-Q' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 as -v --64 -o /tmp/ccrB29rk.o /tmp/ccFkJ2ej.s
GNU assembler version 2.35.2 (x86_64-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.35.2
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-Q' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccnNiHdk.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -pie /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/crtbeginS.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../.. /tmp/ccrB29rk.o -lgcc --push-state --as-needed -lgcc_s --pop-state -lc -lgcc --push-state --as-needed -lgcc_s --pop-state /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-Q' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
```

To sum up, passing `-fleading-underscore` option to gcc triggers linking error, although this option is listed among enabled by default.
Can this be explained?
Also, wasn't gcc producing underscores for each symbol in object files in the past by default? If yes, why has this been changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've submitted a [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=106173) for this. It turned out to be already fixed in GCC 12.1.0.